# Subclassing the UITableViewCell and adding own functionalities in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

How to add a gesture(left to right) which will call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
     //
}
}
```

method to a UITableViewCell by subclassing it in iOS7.

Comment: default feature of ios . If not working try with new viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom class delivered from UITableViewCell and you should add UIPanGestureRecognizer in init:

```
UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

The next step is override method gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[self superview]];
    if (fabsf(translation.x) > fabsf(translation.y)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

and add handlePan:

```
    -(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {   
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            _originalCenter = self.center; //variable to keep centre
        }

        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
            //this check out if you drag more than half of the screen width
            self.center = CGPointMake(_originalCenter.x + translation.x, _originalCenter.y);
            _deleteOnDragRelease = self.frame.origin.x < -self.frame.size.width / 2;
        }

        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            CGRect originalFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y,
                                              self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
            if (!_deleteOnDragRelease) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                 animations:^{
                                     //this is for animate that you move the cell but you don't need it (it just look cool)
                                     self.frame = originalFrame;
                                 }
                 ];
            }
if (_deleteOnDragRelease) {
            // need to implement your delegate
            [self.delegate itemToDeleted:self.YOURDATA];
        }
        }
    }
```

You need to add protocol with method itemToDeleted: and you need to implement it in tableView:commitEditingStyle. Let me know if you need more help with that.
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks @Greg.. Can't we call any table view delegate methods instead of calling handlePan: method to avoid our custom implementation in handlePan: method.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean. If you want to handle this deletion method above you need to implement delegate and set it up for this cell (myTableViewCustomCell.delegate = self) in the file where you keep your tableView delegate. After that you just need to add method: -(void)itemToDeleted:(id)YOURDATA { //handle deletion of YOURDATA}. Is it answering your question?

Comment: Thanks @Greg.. Actually, The UITableViewCell swipe and delete functionality is working fine in both directions (Right To Left, Left To Right) on iOS6. But on iOS7, only One direction(Right To Left) is working. I just wanted to add the Left To Right swipe and delete functionality on iOS7. So that i'm trying to add Left To Right swipe gesture(Which should work same as default Right To Left gesture) to UITableViewCell.

Comment: Yes it should work the same as right to left just add another if (fabsf(translation.x) > fabsf(translation.y)) if, add another method to protocol which will be called  when you detected desire swipe and implement it in your class. This solution is very powerful. You can add any gesture to your uitableviewcell you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `NSMutableArray* sourceArray` as dataSource for your tableView, try something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [sourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, don't forget to set the tableView's delegate and outlet